# Show/Hide Password MVVM Xamarin Forms Checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have been trolling this site, youtube and google to find an answer but I only come up with `EventTriggers` or `ImageSource`.

I have a `LoginPageView` and `LoginPageViewModel` there is an `Entry` for where the user must put in their password and a `CheckBox` which allows the option of viewing the password entered.

I have tried numerous ways to bind and code the `Checkbox` to show the password but I only end up either not succeeding or just permanently showing the password.

I have the code for the **.XAML**

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Password}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Placeholder="Password"
                               PlaceholderColor="White"
                               IsPassword="{Binding IsPass}"
                               x:Name="PasswordBox"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

<CheckBox Color="White"
                              x:Name="ChkShowPass"
                              Margin="25,0,0,0"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckPass}"/>
                    
<Label Text="Show Password"
                           TextColor="White"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="17"
                           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="60"
                           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="4"/>
```

Now the options I have tried for `LoginPageViewModel` are as follows

**Option 1**

```
private bool isCheckPass;
    public bool IsCheckPass
    {
        get { return isCheckPass; }
        set 
        {
            if (isCheckPass != value)
            {
                isCheckPass = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then tried **.XAML**

```
<ImageButton Source="ShowPass.png"
                                 x:Name="BtnShowPass"
                                 Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                 Command="{Binding ToggleIsPassword}">
                        <ImageButton.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                         Binding="{Binding IsPassword}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="HidePass.png" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ImageButton.Triggers>
                    </ImageButton>
```

**.cs in LoginPageViewModel**

```
private bool _IsPass = true;
    public bool IsPass
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsPass;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsPass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsPass");
        }
    }

    public ICommand ToggleIsPassword => new Command(() => IsPass = !IsPass);
```

Please can someone assist here, any and all help welcome.

Comment: in the first example, you need to toggle `IsPass` whenever `IsCheckPass` is changed.  Or you could bind them both to the same property, and use a `InverseBoolConverter` on one of them

Comment: Hi Jason, so what would the `LoginPageViewModel` and `LoginPageView` Code be to toggle `IsPass` whenever `IsCheckPass` changed? I am sorry but I am very new to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You need a converter to convert this for that you can use the InverseBoolConverter as shown below:

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
    {    
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
   }
```

Define it in your XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
 <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

If I were you I would do something like below:

In your ViewModel add a property:

```
public bool IsPasswordVisible
{
   get => isPassword;
   set 
      {
         isPassword = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
}
```

And then In your View, you would Bind them as such:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding IsPasswordVisible, Converter={StaticResoource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                           TextColor="White"
                           FontSize="18"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           Placeholder="Password"
                           PlaceholderColor="White"
                           IsPassword="{Binding IsPass}"
                           x:Name="PasswordBox"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

<CheckBox Color="White"
                          x:Name="ChkShowPass"
                          Margin="25,0,0,0"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsPasswordVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi FreakyAli, thank you very much and I am sorry about my next question here but what would my ViewModel Code be if I want to implement your answer?

Comment: Just set a default value and then when you make changes in your View it will directly affect your Entry

Comment: I am sorry but I am extremely new to all of this and honestly don't know how to do what you are saying, if I make the changes according to  what you stated in your View. I am trying to figure out what of my ViewModel must stay, what must change and where do I add what you said in your ViewModel? I am sorry

Comment: @FreakyAli I believe that `IsPassword` and `IsPasswordVisible` should be inverse of each other - if one is true the other should be false

Comment: Oh yeah @Jason you are right lemme update that

Comment: There is no need to develop an `InverseBoolConverter`, such a thing already exists as part of the **Xamarin.Forms Community Toolkit** (Hint: *xct:InvertedBoolConverter*)

Comment: @ewerspej Xamarin Community toolkit isn't something everyone uses to force someone to use a package just for a converter is a bit too much in my opinion

Comment: That's true, but once you use it, you see that it comes with a lot of useful tools that many apps need anyway. I only wanted to suggest it, because this and other converters come premade.

Comment: I totally agree, if this was MAUI, I would totally recommend it but in Xamarin there are multiple libraries that people use to do different operations and making them use a full-fledged library for a simple converter felt like an overkill to me personally